# Find Vista Language using WIX

Tags: windows-vista, installation, wix, operating-system

I am working on an installer which will be installed on multiple versions of XP/Vista with different languages.
In the installer, I need to find out the language of the OS installed.
I know how to get the OS version by using "**VersionNT**" and/or "**VersionNT64**", is there any similar way to get **OS language** also?

I need to add different registry entries and some files depending on language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [SystemLanguageID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372056%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [UserLanguageID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372384%28VS.85%29.aspx) property.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more windows installer properties.